# What nouns of German origin should be given capital letters?

Tags: capitalization, loanwords, german

On another post an interesting fact has just been discovered about the OED's treatment of nouns adopted into English from German (loan-words).

A lot of them e.g. *Nazi* are spelled with a capital letter. Similar words, which are not of German origin, such as *communist* or *socialist* are not spelled with a capital.

Equally *Zeitgeist*, and *Blitzkrieg* are also given capitals, but interestingly not *kindergarten* or *bratwurst*.

Of course, in German all nouns are given capital letters, not just proper nouns as in English.

What is it that determines whether a noun adopted into English from German should have a capital letter?

Comment: Zeitgeist and blitzkrieg? Capitalized? I don't recall that.  Where does OED say that? Maybe _The_ Blitz, but _a_ blitz. Are you sure you're not seeing these always quoted or standing alone rather than in the middle of a sentence?

Comment: Zeitgeist as a word is not capitlized. The movie Zeitgeist is, though.

Comment: In the first example "Nazi" was the name of a political party, but "communist" and "socialist" are descriptive.

Comment: @Mitch I checked the OED, and the headword for zeitgeist is capitalized, and blitzkrieg has two headwords, one capitalized, one lowercase. Most of the entries for either have their word capitalized. However, neither article has been updated, and no citations are more recent than the 80s (for zeitgeist) and the 60s (for blitzkrieg).

Comment: @Laurel maybe it's a left/right-pondian thing. Merriam-Webster online has none of these words in caps, except for Nazi and even then it has some caps some not (depending on use).

Comment: @Mitch I am talking about the OED headwords. This is from the current online edition. (NB. I am not quoting from any of the multiplicity of small-time dictionaries that describe themselves as Oxford Dictionaries - but from the real thing.)

Comment: @Mitch It probably has to do with time (did you check a *recent* MW?), not pondedness. I suspect that, with time, a word that was brought into English with an initial capital will lose that capital. I would not capitalize either blitzkrieg or zeitgeist, so I think this process has already happened for both of these words. The question makes no sense for anyone looking at an up-to-date dictionary.

Comment: I would say that if one pronounces the borrowed German word **as** a German word  (i.e, using German pronunciation), and if one wishes one's reader to "hear" that German pronunciation in their mind's ear, then one should capitalize the borrowed noun. Thus, _zeitgeist_ is /'zaitgaist/, but _Zeitgeist_ is /'tsaitgaist/.

Comment: There are communists who were never members of say the British  Communist Party, but there were never any Nazis who were not members of (or perhaps fanatics associated with) the Nazi P/party. // Other dictionaries, which one should really consider more reliable than a 50-year-out-of-date OED, give non-capitalised forms of zeitgeist and blitzkrieg.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be addressed  using commonly-available references (ODO, CED, Collins ...) should be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the premise of the question depends upon factual errors.

Comment: @jimm101 And what might those factual errors be?

Comment: @WS2. "Equally Zeitgeist, and Blitzkrieg are also given capitals". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeitgeist https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blitzkrieg

Comment: @jimm101 I wasn't quoting Merriam Webster. I was quoting the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: @WS2 Oxford doesn't use capitals either. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/zeitgeist https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blitzkrieg

Comment: @jimm101 I am not talking about any of the multitude of dictionaries called "Oxford" which abound, and could emanate from anywhere between Yokomama westwards to Albuquerque (though some are published by OUP). I am talking about the online edition of the Oxford English Dictionary, which in its paper form runs to 20 volumes, and is the leading historical authority on the English  language. Go to [www.oed. com.](http://www.oed.com/)

Comment: @WS2 You mean this one? http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/181236;jsessionid=9C968659CDA7F7AC26DD162116AB4A1E?print http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-use/pigskin-and-gridiron-notes-on-the-american-football-lexicon/

Comment: @jimm101 Yes.....

Comment: Those pages don't use capitalization for either zeitgeist and blitzkrieg. The rest appears to be behind a paywall.

Comment: @jimm101 The current online edition is available free-of-charge to most people in the UK, through membership of their local municipal library. You simply input the number on your library card which can be obtained without payment. I am told that some libraries in the US hold subscriptions, making it available to their readers. Now on the edition I have been accessing the position is exactly as I have stated in my question.

Comment: @jimm101Just as a final titbit on the OED, its founder was an American called William Minor, a madman who killed someone in London. Sentenced to be detained in Broadmoor (Britain's principal secure asylum for the criminally insane) he set about the monumental task of compiling the history of the English language. His story is documented in the book "The Surgeon of Crowthorne" by Simon Winchester (1998)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**(1) General concept of nativization**

Languages have a strong tendency to gradually nativize or naturalize loan words. That means that at first,
(i) loan words retain aspects of foreign pronunciations or spelling, 
(ii) are irregular in that they take inflections from their native language, 
(iii) and are used in a specific, unproductive context.

But over time, they 
(i) change their pronunciation and spelling to fit the phonology and orthography of the target language,
(ii) start to be used with native inflections, 
(iii) and appear more productively in a wider range of contexts.

The determinants of this process are:

- **time** - as time goes by, the chances increase that the word will be used like any other native word
- **continued currency** - a word must retain a certain level of use to naturalize; if it becomes too infrequent, it feels exotic, special, salient, or drops out of use altogether
- **structure of the lexicon** - if there are many similar words in the language, it becomes much easier to interpret the word as native

To give one of countless examples, consider the word *baggage*. Originally borrowed from French in the 15th century, 
(i) the word would have been pronounced something like [bagaʒ] but has since been accommodated to native English phonology by adding stress, fronting the vowel [a]>[æ] and strenghtening the final consonant [ʒ]>[dʒ], 
(ii) it would have had a French plural (something like *bagages*), but is now used as a mass noun (*much baggage* rather than ?*many baggages*),
(iii) and it has widened its sense from the sense 'collection of portable property' to, for example, 'psychological burden' (*she carries a lot of baggage from her childhood*), among others.

The word has assimmilated well into the English lexicon because:

- a **lot of time** has been available to naturalize the word
- the word has **remained current** throughout its history
- the English lexicon can easily accommodate the word based on the presence of **many similar words** (e.g. *massage*, *advantage*, *passage* etc.)

**(2) Nativization of recent German borrowings**

The gradual de-capitalization of the relatively recent German borrowings *Zeitgeist* and *blitzkrieg* is one very specific sub-case of the general process of nativization of foreign loan words. It's a gradual process. It is determined by the same factors as listed above.

The words *blitzkrieg* and *Zeitgeist* are only partially naturalized in English at the moment, and that includes their spelling (German capital letter > nativized English lower-case letter), because:

- the words were created in the 1940s and 1840s respectively, i.e. they are relatively young and **more time is needed** to fully assimmilate them into English
- while the words have retained some level of currency, they are **not very common**, but rather exotic, specialized, unusual words - *Blitzkrieg* in particular loosing a lot of relevance - which slows down their nativization
- there are **not a lot of similar words** in the English lexicon - initial *z* is rare and corresponding words are often not native either (*zoology*, *zen*); the graphemes *tz* does exist but it feels foreign as well (*waltz*, *pretzel*) - which is another factor that hinders easy assimmilation into the English lexicon

Some speakers allow for greater nativization of the words and already spell them with a naturalized, lower-case letter whereas other speakers still recognize the foreign source of the words and continue to use the original, upper-case spelling. This is the reason why there is spelling variation today. Over time, as the gradual nativization process continues, the nativized spelling with a lower case letter will likely become the standard spelling.

The following graphs from Google Ngram illustrate the nativization process of recent German loans.

(1) *kindergarten* - borrowed c. 1850, spelling with lower-case letter common from c. 1880.

[image]

(2) *ersatz* - borrowed c. 1875, spelling with lower-case letter common from. c. 1930.

[image]

(3) *wunderkind* - borrowed c. 1890, spelling with lower-case letter common from c. 1970 (also note the gradual plural regularization *Wunderkinder* > *wunderkinds*)

[image]

(4) *schadenfreude* - borrowed c. 1850, spelling with lower-case letter common c. 2010.

[image]

The word *Zeitgeist* was borrowed in the 1840, but as of yet, the spelling with a lower-case letter is not the preferred form. However, there has been a recent increase in that spelling indicating that the word is on its way to naturalization. Additionally, the original plural *Zeitgeister* has now almost completely been replaced by the English plural *zeitgeists*.

[image]

Finally, the word *blitzkrieg* is special. It has lost a lot of its relevance since the 1940s. Hence, there is no linear historical trajectory here. It is also often used as a proper noun (similar to *the Blitz*) so that standard English orthography  would mandate a capital letter anyway. Hence, one would not expect a clean transition from upper to lower case letter. Finally, the word is very marked historically or sociologically. Thus, some speakers may want to highlight the special significance of the word by retaining a capital letter (similar to *Nazi*, *Lebensraum* etc.). The upper and lower case spellings are split more or less 50:50 in the textual record.

[image]

Comment: The reason why the capitalised form of *Zeitgeist* persists may also be that some people perceive it as a proper name: they think of Zeitgeist as *the* one all-encompassing spirit of the current era.

Comment: Thank you *mille fois*. This is a remarkable answer, authoritative, well-argued and very well presented.